# Как правильно использовать sendfile()?

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, unix, posix, http-server

Узнал о вызову senfile(), прочитал про него на man(https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sendfile&category=2&russian=0). Но так и не могу понять, как им пользоваться и что в него передавать. Если брать в качестве примера сервер, то первым аргументом будет серверный сокет, вторым клиентский, а 3 и 4?

как им можно заменить способ, где везде используются send и write?
Вот пример :

```
        if ( (fd=open(path, O_RDONLY))!=-1 )    //FILE FOUND
        {
            static const char hdr[]=
                "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000\r\n";

            send(clients[n], hdr , sizeof(hdr)-1, 0);
            size_t f_sz = fd_size(fd);
            printf("%lu\n",f_sz);
            sprintf (data_to_send, "Content-length: %lu\r\n", f_sz);
            write (clients[n], data_to_send, strlen(data_to_send));
            send(clients[n], "\r\n" , 2, 0);

            while ( (bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES))>0 )
            {
                write (clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Видимо заменить цикл while на `sendfile(clients[n], fd, &offset, f_sz);`, плюс разобраться с опцией TCP_CORK, потому-что в документации как-раз упоминается случай с заголовками, как в примере: `. Если Вы хотите использовать sendfile для пересылки файлов в сокет TCP и требуется послать заголовочные данные в начало содержимого файлов, то обращайтесь за помощью к опции TCP_CORK в tcp(7) Это поможет уменьшить количество пакетов и оптимизировать выполнение функции.`. Ещё переменная нужна, offset, куда функция запишет номер байта, следующего за последним считанным байтом из файла

Comment: @vt-egorov, offset - это указатель на считываемый байт в файле? как его получить?

Comment: Чего? почему указатель? где такое написано?

Comment: @vt-egorov, ну иными словами где сейчас в файле "курсор"?

Comment: @vt-egorov, в любом случае, каким образом это можно получить?

Comment: Вот нормальная [дока](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html). В ней сказано, что если offset равен NULL, то будет прочитано указанное count количество байт, и поле смещения файлового дескриптора будет сдвинуто, то есть следующее чтение будет продолжено с того место, где закончилось чтение в процее работы sendfile. Если offset не равен NULL, то он указывает на переменную, хранящую смещение, начиная с которого надо читать. И поле смещения файлового дескриптора при этом не изменится в процессе sendfile

Comment: Ну то есть если вы просто хотите отправить весь файл, или часть но чтобы следующий клиент читал следующую часть файла - offset = NULL, count - размер части файла для отправки. Если вы хотите отправить весь файл или часть, но при этом иметь возможность следующему клиенту отправить такую же часть файла - заводите переменную. Например, хотите отправить 10 байт с 5-го по 15-ый не включительно 5 клиентам. Заводите переменную offset, и перед каждым вызовом sendfile присваиваете ей 5 и вызываете sendfile, отдавая третьим параметром адрес этой переменной

Comment: Ну по крайней мере так в доке написано, я никогда не использовал эту функцию.

Comment: @vt-egorov, понял, спасибо большое

Comment: Правильно `sendfile` не использовать...

Comment: @user7860670, почему ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
ssize_t sendfile( int out_fd, 
                  int in_fd,
                  off_t *offset,
                  size_t count)
```

первый аргумент - дескриптор открытый для записи (туда пишем),
второй - дескриптор для чтения (оттуда читаем),
третий - смещение откуда нужно начать читать
четвертый - количество данных для передачи.

[источник](man 2 sendfile)

Comment: Вас не смущает различие в названиях функций?

Comment: да, смущает, внес корректировки, спасибо.

Comment: @sopka13 - там в комментариях к вопросу много дополнительной инфы, например, когда нужно указывать offset=NULL. Вы не могли бы добавить эти факты в Ваш ответ? тогда он был бы прямо исчерпывающим...